# Changing variable into actual variable

Tags: php

Wanted to turn value of variable into variable itself.  I am not getting result as expected.

The code, I am getting PHP parse error as syntax error, unexpected '{' on the isset line.

```
$Firstname="Andy";
$item="Firstname";
if(isset(${$item})))
{  echo ${$item};
}
```

I would have expected output of ${$item} would be "Andy"

The code, I am getting PHP parse error as syntax error, unexpected '{' on the isset line.

Comment: You have two opening parentheses and three closing parentheses.

Comment: works fine for me [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/38945e7d2d35f1ba5d95afb34a45c6d571e8bb74) well after removing that extra `)` anyway.

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error. You have extra closing bracket `)` Replace your code with the below code

```
$Firstname="Andy";
$item="Firstname";
if(isset(${$item}))
{  
     echo ${$item};
}
```